# How to upload media to a specific folder without a plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: media, library

Is there anybody who knows an article that explains and shows a code about creating our own plugin for organising media library with folders in the admin? All media that I upload goes in the wp admin section Media -> Library. For example I have uploaded 100 picture and would be nice to be organised in folders. For example Animals, Flowers, ect.

Comment: Do you mean folder IN the media library or specific folders in the uploads directory?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a pretty painful topic in WP.. You need to look for wp_handle_upload() function in the docs. That handles the media upload in case you are not using the wp_media instance. Also, please make the queston more precise. Where do you want to upload it, what do you want to upload? Do you want to use the wp_media instance?

Comment: I am talking about the admin section. Media --> Library. I want to be able to upload pictures the normal way through media --> library --> add new. But I also want to be able during that process to tell the new added picture to go for example in folder Animals. So when I go to Media --> Library to see folders and not 100 unorganised pictures.

Comment: You can use FileBird plugin for free, no need to code